# Folder size difference after folder copy operation from Windows Server to Windows 8.1

Tags: azure, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, filezilla, windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried copying the **wwwroot** directory from Windows Server 2012 R2 data center on Azure Cloud to Windows 8.1 over Remote Desktop Connection and FileZilla, and the copied folder size on Windows 8.1 is much less than the source folder on the server after copy operation completion.

The Source folder size is 683MB while the copied folder is 570MB. I have only found one close explanation for this on support.microsoft.com ([support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362)) which explains that this might be due to long paths that exceed the maximum allowable path length.

I would appreciate if anybody have experience on such matter to enlight me.

Thank you

Comment: Your question would better fit to [su]. It's not really [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Server Fault, I think, rather than Super User.

Answer (score 0):

A typical cause of these symptoms is that you have used an ascii/text transfer mode, so all CRLF line-endings got converted to CR only (one byte less for each line).

But you have provided way too little information, so we can only guess.

---

Download the directory tree back (to another folder) and compare against your original source folder.

Check if the problem is specific to a certain folder/file only or if all (or majority of) files got reduced proportionally.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.
I used copy/paste on the type which looks like TeamViewer remote connection where I can see the desktop and everything.